# Issue in the Flow of my Html/CSS code

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning web development specially CSS, i know JS and HTML but not CSS. i am trying to creat web page using bootstrap, but i am stuck in Navbar of it and not able to move further.
below are the issues i am facing

1. i have a header bar which has 100px height, and then Nav bar which has 55px height and then main content. When i use chrome dev tool and inspect element on these Div's even though they are one after the other(assumed flow will be one after the other), dev tool shows everything starts at top 0 position. Can anyone please teem y this is happening, and how i can fix it.
2. The header bar is added so that i can place the nav bar lil lower then very top, what happens is when i give some background color to header bar and then try to re-size the browser to small, this header bar hides away.
3. One more issue with Services Div, when i click on service div it doesnt show up.

It would be good if anyone help me with explanation.

Please look at the code in the below link, by looking at the demo you will know the issues i am talking about.

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tHCBD

**HTML**

```
<meta charset=”utf-8”>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container">  
    <div id="header" class="container"> </div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top container" role="navigation">
          <div class="container inside-bar">  
                 <ul class="nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#OurStaff">Our Staff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#book">book</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Gift">Gift Cards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                 </ul>
          </div>  
        </nav>
          <div id="mainContent">
            <div id='Services' class="box">
               Services
            </div>
            <div id='about' class="box">
               About
            </div>
            <div id='OurStaff' class="box">
               Our Staff
            </div>
            <div id='book' class="box">
               book
            </div>
            <div id='Gift' class="box">
               Gift
            </div>
            <div id='Reviews' class="box">
               Reviews
            </div>
         </div> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to achieve something [like here](http://appizy.com/examples/bs-onepage/) with a navbar fixed on top and some smooth navigation to the different section.

You might want to use [Appizy](http://appizy.com) for that. You just have to organize your content in a spreadsheet and then the software makes it live for you. [Check the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyyzT5rxI5U).

Hope that can help.

Comment: No, I dont want to implement like that. I dont want the navbar to be there on the top.

Comment: Your example looks a bit like it with a fixed nav-bar. You can start from my example and then "pimp" it with some CSS I guess.